# How to randomly assign to vector in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I am new to C++, and am continuously told to use `std::vector` instead of `new[]`.

I am trying to achieve this functionality, in where I know the size of the vector and want to assign to it randomly (not sequentially).

However, when running this, my program terminates with no error output, so I am stumped.

```
vector<string> v1;
v1.resize(2);
v1.insert(v1.begin() + 1, "world");
v1.insert(v1.begin() + 0, "world");

cout << v1.at(1) << endl;
```

Comment: "arrays (just pointers)" What do you mean by this? Arrays are absolutely not "just pointers".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I mean instead of using vector<cv::Mat>, use cv::Mat*

Comment: So you mean a pointer to a dynamically-allocated block of memory large enough to hold `N` contiguous `cv::Mat` objects.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Don't give up, it's easier than that

```
vector<string> v1(2);
v1[1] = "world";
v1[0] = "world";

cout << v1[1] << endl;
```

`vector::insert` is for when you want to add items to your vector, Not when you want to replace ones that are already there, `vector::insert` changes the size of the vector in other words.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but I wanted to post the exact equivalent of the OP's code.

Comment: How do you achieve this if the class does not have a default constructor, because then resize does not work

Comment: @Aly: Almost all classes have a default constructor.  For the few that don't, simply pass an object to copy from to the constructor as well as the count.   `std::vector<std::string> v1(2, "HI");`

Comment: @MooingDuck the class that I am containing is my own, is it the practice to have a default constructor (although using this class if its been default constructed makes no sense)?

Comment: @Aly: if it doesn't make sense to have a default constructor, then don't give it one. That's fine.  You'll have to pass an instance for the `vector` to copy from when using resizing functions though.  Which is fine.  `v1.resize(4, "HI");`

Comment: @Aly. If it doesn't make sense then no. Don't add one just to make containers work easier. You're on the right track: use .insert twice or provide a default to .resize as suggested above... Then edit the elements as shown in the answer using op[]

Answer (score 12):

First you resize it to have two empty strings:

```
{"", ""}
```

Then you insert `"world"` before `begin() + 1` or the 2nd element:

```
{"", "world", ""}
```

Then you insert `"world"` before `begin()` or the 1st element:

```
{"world", "", "world, ""}
```

Then you access the 2nd element with `v1.at(1)` and get the empty string.

Presumably, you don't want [`std::vector::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) which inserts new elements between existing elements. You want to do this as you would with arrays, with [`operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at):

```
vector<string> v1(2);
v1[1] = "world";
v1[0] = "world";
cout << v1.at(1) << endl;
```

Answer (score 10):

To randomly **assign**

Simply use the index (obviously, validate that it's < `size`)

```
v1[index] = value;
```

To randomly **insert** (validate that index < `size`)

```
v1.insert(v1.begin() + index, value);
```

To sequentially **insert at the end / append** (no need for an index, your value will be inserted at the end of the vector)

```
v1.push_back(value);
```

If you plan on inserting many values, consider calling `reserve()` on your vector so that enough memory can be allocated to store all of your items, otherwise as you insert your data you may end up with many reallocation as the vector grows

Comment: +1, may want to reword push_back to append vs insert. to me at least seems more semantically and conceptually accurate

Comment: I can't call resize if the class does not have a default constructor correct? In this case how do I have a vector of a certain size and randomly assign. Or do I just have to create an empty vector and just keep inserting?

Comment: Exactly, if your vector contains "objects" instead of "pointers to objects", every time the vector grows the objects will be copied (which is very inefficient), consider storing pointers for big objects and copy constructors for your objects.

Comment: @Aly: You can pass an object to copy from to the constructor, or to the resize function for the case of classes with no default constructor.  Works just fine.

Comment: @emartel: He wasn't asking about effeciency of copies nor pointers.  He was asking how resize works on classes with no default constructor.

Comment: @MooingDuck well, passing to pointers makes the constructor of the object irrelevant. If he didn't knew about the hidden tax of growing a vector of objects, I believe the info is relevant.

Comment: @emartel If I store a vector of pointers, how does cleanup work? when the vector is no longer being referenced do all of the pointers get cleaned up too?

Comment: @Aly no, you need to a) allocate the object, b) insert / push_back to your vector and c) when you destroy the vector (ie in its owner's destructor) you need to manually go through every element of your vector and call delete on it

Comment: I wouldn't use a vector of objects unless they are very simple (plain old data (int, float, etc...) or simple objects composed of a few plain old data members - ie.: a 3D vector that has a x, y and z component)

Answer (score 6):

Your Program is working correctly. Your error is in the logic of your code.

Insert doesn't change the string stored at index 1.  It places a string at position 1, and moves all indexes after 1 to the right.

```
start               first insert            second insert 
("","")      ->   ("", "world, "")    ->  ("world","","world","")
```

So when you print v1.at(1) you are printing an empty string.

To fix the issue, you would want to use:

```
v1.at(1)="world"
v1.at(0)="world"
```

--or--

```
v1[1] ="world"
v1[0] ="world"
```

The two solutions are equivalent, however the second will not do any bounds checking.  The first will throw an error if there is an out of bounds error.  This shouldn't matter as long as you can gaurantee that you will never index out of bounds.

Answer (score 2):

Like many have stated, you can can just use `operator[]` to reassign old values, given that you've already sized the vector or filled it with other values.
If your array will always have a fixed size you can use `std::array`, which should provide a performance boost, at the sacrifice of the ability to resize the array or determine its size at runtime.

```
std::array<std::string,2> a1;
a1[0] = "world";
a1[1] = "world2";
std::cout<<a1.at(1)<<std::endl; //outputs world2
```

Note that the size must be static, so you can't do something like this:

```
int numStrings;
std::cin>>numStrings;
std::array<std::string,numStrings> a2; //ERROR
```

Unfortunately, I don't think there is any way of initializing an `std::array` without a default constructor, other than using an initialization list.

```
struct T
{
   T(std::string s):str(s){} //no default constructor
   std::string str;
}
std::array<T,2> a3 = {T(""), ""}; //you can use a conversion constructor implicitly
```

Obviously, this isn't practical if you want an array with a sizable number of objects.