# Randomly assign to boost::ptr_vector

Tags: c++, pointers, boost, vector, ptr-vector

I want to randomly assign to a boost::ptr_vector. Using the normal STL vector I would do this:

```
class A{

};

A* a1 = new A();
A* a2 = new A();

vector<A*> normal_vec;
normal_vec.resize(2);
normal_vec[1] = a1;
normal_vec[0] = a2;
```

I am trying to do the same with boost::ptr_vector:

```
A* a1 = new A();
A* a2 = new A();

ptr_vector<A> boost_vec;
boost_vec.resize(2);

boost_vec[1] = a1;
boost_vec[0] = a2;
```

But am getting the following error:

```
no match for ‘operator=’ in ‘v.boost::ptr_vector<A>::<anonymous>.boost::ptr_sequence_adapter<T, VoidPtrSeq, CloneAllocator>::operator[] [with T = A, VoidPtrSeq = std::vector<void*, std::allocator<void*> >, CloneAllocator = boost::heap_clone_allocator, boost::ptr_sequence_adapter<T, VoidPtrSeq, CloneAllocator>::reference = A&, boost::ptr_sequence_adapter<T, VoidPtrSeq, CloneAllocator>::size_type = long unsigned int](1ul) = a1’
```

But am struggling to make sense of this

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13367079/how-to-randomly-assign-to-vector-in-c

Comment: Seems like you haven't been reading the documentation for the types you're using.

Comment: Your `std::vector` example is not how one typically adds to a `vector`. Use `push_back` (after optionally calling `reserve`) instead of `operator[]`.

Comment: The whole point of a `boost::ptr_vector` is that you do *not* see the pointers.

Comment: @Praetorian I want to assign randomly i.e. not to the 0th then the 1st index (see above) I do v[1] followed by v[0]

Comment: You can always shuffle an ordered vector, or push a randomly chosen object instance into the vector instead.

Comment: @Rook I dont want it to have a random order, but I want to assign to it in a non-sequential manner.

Comment: You might want to clarify that in your question, _"I want to randomly assign to a boost::ptr_vector"_, especially given that the end result of random insertion and sequential insertion of random elements is the same...

Comment: @Rook the title is "Randomly assign to boost::ptr_vector"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `ptr_vector<T>::replace` instead of `operator[]`. The `operator[]` returns `T&` instead of `T*&`, so you can only assign value not a pointer.

Also note that you have a memory leak when the second `new` for `a2` throws, `a1` is not deleted in the code below:

```
A* a1 = new A();
A* a2 = new A();
```

Consider using `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: Sorry, can you clarify the memory leak? Is this just in the first code block? If so, I understand. If its in the second code blocked I'm puzzled as I thought the ptr_vector handles the deletes

Comment: He means that when allocating `A* a2 = new A()`, if that allocation fails, then there is no way the first allocation `A *a1 = new A()`, would get deleted by the code because its not handled. Hence the reason why he suggested using a smart pointer. But if this is a small application, then you shouldn't have to worry about stuff like these, although you should generally use smart pointers, any allocation that hasn't been deleted will be taken care by OS after program exits.

Answer (score 0):

Also note your program has a bug. Indexing starts at 0 not 1.

Comment: Thanks, was a type should have been v[1], v[0] ( I want them to be out of order)